# Why does z3.check() slow when it is immediately preceded by z3.push()?

Tags: z3, z3py

The below Python snippet illustrates a strage performance behavior of Z3.  Without `push()` call, the z3 checks the formula in 0.1s.  With `push()` (and no extra assertions), z3 takes 0.8s.  A similar outcome occurs even after swapping `s.append(f)` and `s.push()`.

```
import time
import z3
f = z3.parse_smt2_file("smt-lib/QF_BV/RWS/Example_1.txt.smt2")
s = z3.Solver()
s.append(f)
t1 = time.time()
s.check()  # 0.10693597793579102 seconds
print(time.time() - t1)

s = z3.Solver()
t1 = time.time()
s.append(f)
s.push()
s.check()  # 0.830916166305542 seconds
print(time.time() - t1)
```

Any idea why does this slowdown occur?  And, how can it be addressed?

I'm using z3-4.3.2.bb56885147e4-x64-osx-10.9.2.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good repro. Z3 uses the incremental solver for the second instance. It is not clear from the use case why this should be the case, so it points to a usability bug. Internally, Z3 uses a factory pattern to create solvers. I am looking into whether this is where the cause is or whether it is a side-effect of the previous solver that overrides the state.

Comment: @NikolajBjorner The behavior is the same even when the snippets are executed in different Python processes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example uses "push" in the second instantiation.
This makes a huge difference.
Z3's bit-vector solver is (not yet) amenable to incremental use over the API.
It works only for stand-along assertions and does not interoperate with scopes (push/pop).
The first invocation uses the bit-vector SAT solver. There is no "push/pop" going on.
The second invocation follows a call to "push". Z3 then determines that in order to track scope dependencies it has to use the incremental SMT core, which does not benefit from the more efficient bit-vector solver.

Comment: So, would you recommend accumulating assertions external to Z3 and using a non-scoped instance of the solver?